# How does Captain America know this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

Near the end of Captain America, Tony Stark discovers

> the video where Bucky kills his parents.

Then he asks Cap' if he knew. He says yes.

How does he know?

> I can't remember Bucky telling him. Is there any official answer?